# Returns a point interpolated along a line using geopandas

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas

Is there a function like Postgis ST_Line_Interpolate_Point in GeoPandas?

Comment: Geopandas uses Shapely that has an Interpolate method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was [mentioned by @klewis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256537/returns-a-point-interpolated-along-a-line-using-geopandas#comment404930_256537), Shapely methods can be used in GeoPandas.  Shapely has the [**interpolate**](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#object.interpolate) method which will

> Return a point at the specified distance along a linear geometric object.

It also has the `normalized` argument.

> If the normalized arg is `True`, the distance will be interpreted as a fraction of the geometric object’s length.

This is probably the most analogous function to [**ST_Line_Interpolate_Point**](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_Line_Interpolate_Point.html) which

> Returns a point interpolated along a line. Second argument is a float8
>   between 0 and 1 representing fraction of total length of linestring
>   the point has to be located.